# C++ Forward Declaring Classes Within Classes

Tags: c++

The following simple piece of code compiles, although I don't understand why:

```
class C {
    class B;

    class A {
        B getB() { return B(); }
    };

    class B {
    };
};

int main(int, char**)
{
    return 0;
}
```

If I then comment out the "`class C`" stuff, so that the forward declaration of `B`, the definition of `A` and the definition of `B` are no longer nested within a class, the code does not compile, since `B` is of an incomplete type:

```
main.cpp: In member function 'B A::getB()':
main.cpp:6: error: return type 'struct B' is incomplete
main.cpp:6: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct B'
main.cpp:3: error: forward declaration of 'struct B'
```

I understand what it means for a type to be incomplete, namely that it has not been defined yet and so the compiler can't possibly know how much space to allocate for it. But why is `B` not considered incomplete in the code above, where `A` and `B` are both declared and defined inside of `C`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is a consequence of [[basic.scope.class]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.class#1):

> The potential scope of a name declared in a class consists not only of the declarative region following the
>   name’s point of declaration, but also of all function bodies, default arguments, *exception-specifications*, and *brace-or-equal-initializers* of non-static data members in that class (including such things in nested
>   classes).

That is, the scope of the *full* declaration of `B` includes the body of the member function of the nested class:

```
class C {
    class B; // (1)

    class A { 
        B getB() {
            return B(); // both (1) and (2) in scope here
                        // since (2) is the complete type declaration,
                        // this is perfectly fine
        }
    };

    class B { // (2)
    };
};
```

By comparison, if `C` were a namespace instead of a class, the scope of the full declaration of class `B` would not extend into `A::getB()`. The only visible declaration would be the forward-declaration of `B` that I labeled `(1)` -  so `B()` would be the construction of an incomplete type there.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clearing that up. What brought up this particular question is libpqxx's [`result`](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/stable/html/Reference/) class, which has nested `tuple` and `field` classes, in which `tuple` constructs a `field` in one of its function bodies (namely, line 183)

Answer (score 9):

The body of an inline member function is not processed until the class definition has been fully processed.

Hence, you can use:

```
class A 
{
   class B;
   B getB() { return B(); }

   class B {};
};
```

That also allows member variables that are not yet declared to be used in inline member function definition.

```
class Foo
{
   int getBar() { return bar; }

   int bar;
};
```

I am guessing the same logic is extended to inline definitions of member functions of nested classes -- i.e. they are not processed until the containing class definition is completely processed.

**PS** I am unable to quickly locate the reference in the standard that would verify my claim.

**PS 2** [The answer by Barry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35927869/434551) has the reference in the standard that makes the code in the question valid.

Comment: You beat me to the answer.  I was trying to find the standaries.  I think it is convered by *Similarly during name lookup, when an unqualified-id (5.1) used in the definition of
a member function for class X resolves to a static member, an enumerator or a nested type of class X or of a
base class of X, the unqualified-id is transformed into a qualified-id (5.1) in which the nested-name-specifier
names the class of the member function.* from **[class.mfct.non-static]**.  If you agree go ahead and use it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't think that's right. That just says that `B` will be found - but `B` would be found regardless due to the forward-declaration. I don't know where the right section is tho, can't find it either.

Comment: Maybe *If class X is defined in a namespace scope, a nested class Y may be declared in class X and later defined in the
definition of class X or be later defined in a namespace scope enclosing the definition of class X.* from **[class.nest]**

Comment: @NathanOliver That part (even though the example is tantalizingly close) basically just allows you to forward declare nested classes.

Comment: I'm still looking.

Comment: @NathanOliver At least it's definitely, probably not in the templates clause.

Comment: @NathanOliver Actually, I think I found it.

Answer (score 5):

The standard is explicit in mandating that the method's body is interpreted after the class that encloses it.

Thus at the time of evaluating the body of `C::A::getB()`, `A`, `B` and `C` are all complete types.

Comment: Any chance you might know where I could find that verbiage?

Comment: trying to find it... unfortunately, the term "member function" is mentioned 582 times in the 2015 draft standard PDF... http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Besides that when I've got the need to forward declare nested classes I tend to smell some bad design in my code, the trick I use is:

```
// Foo.h
class Foo {
    class Bar {
    };
};
class Foobar : public Foo::Bar {};


// Zoo.h
/* Fwd declare */
class FooBar;
```